# What is the source code of implementation of EOS Blockchain latest version?

Tags: development, dpos, governance

Please provide the link for the latest version of EOS blockchain source code. We are trying to implement concurrency in EOS Blockchain. But for that, we need to analyze the whole code and we should find the scope where we can implement concurrency and after that, we should integrate the concurrency algorithms we have on to EOS Blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

The latest EOS source code is available here: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos